How do you solve this incline plane forces question?
Question

I would greatly appreciate any assistance solving this question!
Working out so far


I think you are confused by the problem setup. They talk about a first case, when there is no force $H$ applied, and the angle of the plane is $\alpha$. This means that $$N=mg\cos\alpha\\\mu N=mg\sin\alpha$$
form which you can find $\mu=\tan\alpha$. In the second case the angle of the plane is $\theta$. In this case, in the direction perpendicular to the plane you have $$N=mg\cos\theta+H\sin\theta$$
In the direction along the plane you get two options, depending if the object starts to slide up or down (the fiction is always opposite direction to the velocity). For example,when the object starts to move up, friction is downwards $$H\cos\theta=mg\sin\theta+\mu N=mg\sin\theta+\tan\alpha(mg\cos\theta+H\sin\theta)$$
Moving the $H$ terms to one side, you get
$$H(\cos\theta-\tan\alpha\sin\theta)=mg(\sin\theta+\tan\alpha\cos\theta)$$
You can rewrite this as $$H=\frac{mg(\sin\theta+\tan\alpha\cos\theta)}{\cos\theta-\tan\alpha\sin\theta}$$
Dividing both numerator and denominator by $\cos\theta$ you get $$H=mg\frac{\tan\theta+\tan\alpha}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\theta}=mg\tan(\alpha+\theta)$$
Solving for the other case means that the friction is upward, or $$H\cos\theta+\mu N=mg\sin\theta$$
